# Where is the $HOME environment variable set?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I'm looking for the place where $HOME environment variable set.
It is after login, to my mind.

I'm using Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to change it:
https://superuser.com/a/694428/76871

(it is defined in `/etc/passwd`; edit it with `usermod -d /some/new/home/dir myusername`, though modifying the file may work)

---

When the home directory is written to the $HOME environment variable:
https://superuser.com/a/271935/76871
https://superuser.com/a/271927/76871

(the string is passed in as an argument to the login program, which will later set the $HOME env var)

---

sidenote: When the $HOME variable is not defined, the bash shell will fetch it from its official definition in `/etc/passwd` and define it in that script. This may indicate that your scripting or programming language may have special treatment for the $HOME variable since it is slightly 'important' (though perhaps not as much as $PATH).

https://superuser.com/a/1502106/76871

Comment: You are likely confusing `$HOME` with `$PATH`. It does not make sense to have multiple paths in `$HOME` (the entire value will be treated as a single pathname) or, in most cases, to modify `$HOME` at all.

Comment: @grawity: oops sorry, thank you. Sadly I cannot delete my answer.

Comment: I have fixed this answer by editing it, now that I can edit answer on this site.

Answer (score 35):

On Linux, the `HOME` environment variable is set by the login program:

- by `login` on console, *telnet* and *rlogin* sessions
- by `sshd` for SSH connections
- by `gdm`, `kdm` or `xdm` for graphical sessions.

Answer (score 10):

The login program arranges it before calling exec on your shell (by including it in the arguments to exec), based on the value in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Interesting this did not get more votes.  It's the only answer that actually specifies **where** the environment variable is set, which was the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 7):

Edit this by running: `usermod -d /home/whatever_dir whatever_user`.

Please note that this will (obviously) be the new home directory.  Bash will `cd` to it on login, so make sure it exists and the permissions are correct.  In addition, don't forget about `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.xinitrc`, etc; if they're not in the home directory, they will not be read.

From `usermod`:

```
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                him/her from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
```

Answer (score 5):

I did some digging, and the answer to this is a bit surprising. Take the following test script and `chmod +x` it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
printf 'My home is: '
echo  ~ || echo 'nowhere'
```

We can run it with `./test.sh` and see:

> My home is: /home/user

Let's take a peek under the hood with strace.

`$ strace ./test.sh |& grep '^open[a-z]*'`

> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty",
>   O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "./test.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3

I do not see any mention of HOME, rc files, or passwd. Let's try it with a clean env:

```bsh
env -i bash
echo $HOME  #this will be blank since we cleared the env
```

> 

Nothing, as expected. Let's run the script in the blank env.

```bsh
env -i bash
./test.sh
```

> My home is: /home/user

Interesting, the script is able to get home. Now let's trace.

```
strace ./test.sh |& grep '^open[a-z]*'
```

Now we see:

> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty",
>   O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3 
> **openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3** 
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> openat(AT_FDCWD,
>   "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
>   
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
> **openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd",
>   O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3** 
> openat(AT_FDCWD, "./test.sh", O_RDONLY) =
>   3

I've bolded the interesting lines. As we can see, it would appear that when `$HOME` is not defined, the shell will try to fill it in, even when not in login or interactive mode.